# Sequential access of 1-Wire devices

Tags: arduino, 1-wire

I need to access sequentially 64 1-wire devices by indexing them, this because i need to know the exact position of those single devices (for example, the DS2401 on position 25 has 000xFFF456 serial).

I've seen the Maxim DS2482-800 that allows me to select up to 8 1-Wire devices...but the part pricing is too high.

Do you guys have some sort of alternative?

Comment: You don't need that chip. You can select a device by command. Have a look at https://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/OneWire/ and read the datasheet of your 1-wire devices.

Comment: Yeah, i know, but the initial condition is that i don't know the serial of the specific device for example at position 22 and i need to track the serial and position in the bus.

Comment: Do you need them all common to a single bus? if no, then use a mux / set of mux chips to redirect the data line in the order you want

Comment: No, i don't need them in a single bus, i was planning to use a set of CD4051 mux in cascade, it's a good idea?

Comment: What microcontroller or logging system are you using? If I were hanging these off a micro, I'd probably do it programmatically. Write a little script to continuously log them all, then go along them one at a time, closing a solder joint or something, and see which order they appear on your bus.